# leds-pwm driver in linux 3.8

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using custom board based on beaglebone black. I am trying to enable leds-pwm driver in Linux 3.8 version. But Kconfig says the driver `depends on HAVE_PWM` config, I am not able to see that configuration anywhere.

After spending some time i think linux3.8(or atleast linux3.8 from TI) doesn't support led-pwm driver.

Has any one tried to enabled leds-pwm driver in Linux3.8 ? how to enable it ?
Any suggestions ?

I am trying to enable driver config in following path in menuconfig:
*`Device Drivers` ⇒ `LED Supports` ⇒ `PWM driven LED Support`*.

Any pointers/suggestions will help.

Answer (score 2):

`HAVE_PWM` (as all `HAVE_*` config parameters) isn't a parameter you are supposed to change.  As the name suggests, it just tells something about the platform you're compiling the kernel for and is enabled by the platform you have selected (e.g. if you select "NXP LPC32XX" [`CONFIG_ARCH_LPC32XX`] it gets enabled since this platform supports PWM).

If you selected the correct platform in your configuration and `HAVE_PWM` isn't enabled, there's most likely no support for PWM on this platform (either because the kernel doesn't support it on that platform or the platform doesn't support it in the first place).

Comment: Thank you for reply, there is PWM support on the board, but it seems led-pwm support is not there.